# Null Pointer Exception on dataBase.query

Tags: apex

```
public string getAllData(ObjectName,Fields){

sobjectList=Database.query(Select id,AccountName from contact limit1);
}

Here Object=Conatct ,fields =Id,AccountName

 for(sObject SobjectRecord : SobjectList){
 String.valueOf(SobjectRecord.get('AccountName'));--error null pointer-exception
 }
```

can i get any solution  ??

Answer (score 4):

You need to query `account.name`. you can't access accountname using this way.

Because there is no such Field `AccountName` on contact
.[image]
You will get error like 
[image]

You can Do something like this

```
List<sObject> sobjectList=Database.query('Select id,Account.Name from contact limit1');
for(contact SobjectRecord : (List<contact>)SobjectList){
 System.debug(SobjectRecord.Account.Name);
 }
```

to get the details.

[image]
[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

**Update**

As you want to get parent field dynamically then you need to something like

```
List<sObject> sobjectList=Database.query('Select id,Account.Name from contact limit1');
for(sObject SobjectRecord : SobjectList){
 sObject sa = SobjectRecord.getSobject('Account');
    if(sa != null)
            System.debug(sa.get('Name'));
 }
```

[image]

In your case you need to store all field in a List and then if that string contains `.` then you need to split that and get the value;

You can use this piece of code..Althouh this is not the best code but you can easily develop something useful using this. This is dynamic

```
List<string> fldList = new List<string>();
fldList.add('account.name');
fldList.add('Id');
List<sObject> sobjectList=Database.query('Select id,Account.Name from contact limit1');
for(sObject SobjectRecord : SobjectList){
    for(string str : fldList)
    {

        if(str.split('\\.').size() > 1)
        {
            sObject sa = SobjectRecord.getSobject(str.split('\\.')[0]);
            if(sa != null)
                System.debug(sa.get(str.split('\\.')[1]));
        }
        else
        {
            System.debug(SobjectRecord.get(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: @govind123raju - Your comments really do not inspire one to help. Feels kinda like harassing to me. I suggest you sit back and think about how to write a good question and try again as I do not believe anyone has any idea what you are trying to get at here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44648/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-sharma-null-pointer-exception-on-database-query).